# Image view crush stackview constraints in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, constraints, uistackview

I have some issue about my stackview contraints or imageview constraints ı dont know actually.Probably both . This is my stackview constraints [stackViewConst](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYQ4q.png) and this my imageview constraints [imaviewConstraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fg72E.png) . When ı try to run ı expect everything looks awesome however unfortunately ı get this screen [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9K4MO.png) my stackview is lost.How ı can figure out this help me

Comment: What happens if you also add stackview height constraint ?

Comment: Thanks for advice it worked perfectly.But ı cant figure out something.Why is it worked what is the reason.Can you explain me @Mr.SwiftOak

Comment: Setting the vertical compression resistance of the UILabels to .required (1000) might also do the trick. But just a guess since I cannot say anything about the rest of the layout

Comment: Thanks for advice this method is also worked .But ı wondering about why is worked plz explain to me . Why do you think like that . I am new in swift so sorry for that multiple questions ı just wanna have knowledge wihout any memorization @DanielMarx

Comment: @Sait47 I added some explanation into the answer below.

Comment: https://betterprogramming.pub/what-are-content-hugging-and-compression-resistance-in-swift-60275f6dc69e might give you some insights

Comment: Thanks for everything bro.Love you too @DanielMarx

Comment: @Sait47 Sure, no problem!  I would however also appreciate if you accept my answer, so that it will be counted into my personal stackoverflow rating. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I have already approved your answer ahhah @Mr.SwiftOak

Comment: @Sait47 This link shows what I actually meant. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer**: **add stackview height constraint**
(or add stack view content resistence and content hugging priorities higher than those of your `UIImageView`)

**Explanation**:
Since you are using storyboard's Interface builder (IB) for creating constraints, as opposed to pure code. The IB uses feature of auto-constraints, which basically means that the IB can figure itself the layout and constraints  based on what is displayed in your storyboard. The `UIStackView` is using some dynamic resizing (so that elements within stackview are properly layed out) and it is always good idea to give it size constraints, or at least size constraints to elements inside `UIStackView` , otherwise it might decide that every element has size of `CGSize(height:0,width:0)` You can also make priorities of your `UIStackView` higher than those of your `UIImageView` so that IB would prioritize the size of your `stackview`'s constraints to those of your `imageView`